# jquery: How to get dropdown option sequence number?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, sequence

Example:

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option value="A">First</option>
    <option value="B">Second</option>
    <option value="C" selected="selected">Third</option>
    <option value="D">Fourth</option>
</select>
```

Using jquery, I want to get the *selected* option **sequence number**, which is "3"

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var val =$('#myselect option:selected').val();
  alert(val) // alerts C
  var txt =$('#myselect option:selected').text();
  alert(txt) // alerts Third  
  var seqNo=$('#myselect option:selected').index()+1; // +1 because first element counted as zero
  alert(seqNo); // gives the required sequence number
});
</script>
```

Comment: That gives the value, which is "C", I want the sequence of the option

Comment: @evilReiko, I have updated code for sequence number for selected dropdown.

Answer (score 3):

Use `index()` method to find a position of the matched element within the collection relative to its siblings.

```
var index = $('#myselect option:selected').index() + 1;
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/index/
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7wUK6/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#myselect option:selected').index() + 1
```